# Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy

Tags: python, numpy, heroku

my project run local on pycharm without error but when i deployed it on heroku
 error message appears :Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.
 i changed numpy version more than one but it does not work

Django Version:     2.2.5

Exception Type:     ImportError

Exception Value: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py in , line 26

Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python

Python Version:     3.6.10

numpy version : 1.18.1

any solution?

Comment: You're using the same package versions locally and on Heroku?

Comment: yes ,the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it

my solution was

Run locally   1- python -m pip install python-dev-tools

then  2- pip freeze > requirements.txt

3-git add .

4-git commit -m "v5"

5- heroku git:remote -a "your appname on heroku"

6-git push heroku master